# ASP NET MVC - Download de tabela html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*Tenho uma view que tem toda uma estrutura de tabela, digitando o caminho da view na barra de navegação abri a tabela.
Gostaria de criar um botão que baixasse essa tabela e salvasse como .xls
Alguem consegue me ajudar?
Já procurei e so encontrei baixando caso criasse a tabela de outras formas e não a tabela já criada em html.
Agradeço.
Abs,*

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt" bgcolor="#F0F8FF ">

        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"> </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="gray">   <b>Tópico </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#d3d3d3"><b>   Keyword </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#d3d3d3"><b>   Total de Postagens </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#d3d3d3"><b>   Alcance Total</b>   </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#9be29b"><b>   Positivas</b>   </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#FFFACD"><b>   Neutras  </b> </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none" bgcolor="#ff9999"><b>   Negativas  </b> </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none"> <b>  Twitter   </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none"> <b>  Facebook  </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none"> <b>  Instagram </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none"> <b>  Youtube   </b>  </td>
        <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none"> <b>  Outras    </b>  </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"> </td>
    </tr>

<tr height="20" style="height:15.0pt">

            <td></td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@topico.name</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@topico.name</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@posts.Count</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@reach</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@positivo</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@neutro</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@negativo</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@twitterCount</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@facebookCount</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@instagramCount</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@youtubeCount</td>
            <td align="center" class="xl68" style="border-left:none">@outros</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A tabela possui paginação?

Comment: A princípio você quer criar um `crawler`, que irá ler os dados HTML da página, populando um .xls com os mesmos?

Comment: você consegue colocar um trecho do seu código? facilitaria para o pessoal ajudar com isso

Comment: Na verdade esse html que tenho na View já é uma tabela completa, bem simples, sem CSS. Se clico com o botão contrário nela consigo salvar e coloco.xls e ela abri no EXCEL.

Comment: Rodrigo, seria mais ou menos isso aqui, com mais linhas. https://jsfiddle.net/52fLry0s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você criar uma `Action` em seu controller com o [cabeçalho HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx) que deseja, no seu caso para `.xls`.

Em termos de código, ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
   public ActionResult ExportarParaExcel()
    {
        var lista = db.ENTIDADE.ToList();//Sua lista que está enviando apra View.

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NOMEARQUIVO.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        return View(lista);

    }
```

Da forma acima você não precisa realizar alteração nenhuma em sua `view`. Basta colocar as duas linhas em sua `Action` já funcionando que verá o resultado.

Comment: Dificil acreditar que era tão simples.
Obrigado demais pela ajuda Randrade!

Comment: @ArthurKeller Muitas coisas são simples assim. Eu também me surpreendi quando descobri. kk

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando `jQuery` e `window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel)`...

Fiz um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/u0zz2pxz/) pra você testar, mas basicamente você precisa exportar o HTML da sua tabela.

Supondo seu html:

```
<div id="divResultado">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Carro</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@data</td>
            <td>@hora</td>
            <td>@carro</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

E o botão:

```
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Exportar para excel " />
```

E como sua `<table>` está dentro da div `#divResultado`, no JQuery:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#divResultado').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Marllon, muito obrigado pela ajuda, entretanto, testei primeiro a opção do amigo a cima, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, há várias formas de fazer... mas pelo que você escreveu, deu a impressão que você não queria ir na base de dados novamente... eu entendi que você quisesse exportar a tabela que estava no HTML... por isso sugeri a abordagem por jQuery.. :)